# what is the problem with this wso2 analytics dashboard error

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

my scenario is about two servers one running wso2 api manager and one running wso2 analytics and I want to show statics of api manager on analytics server .how to configure this servers? (analytics dashboard conf , analytics worker conf , api manager conf) thanx

```
WARN {org.wso2.msf4j.internal.MSF4JHttpConnectorListener} - Unmapped exception 
feign.RetryableException: No subject alternative names matching IP address 192.168.115.132 
found executing GET https://192.168.115.132:9443/api/am/admin/v1/custom-urls/carbon.super
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the hostname verification. The recommended option is to use proper certs with hostnames. Otherwise, you can disable hostname verification by adding the following.

```
hostnameVerificationEnabled: false
```

https://github.com/wso2/docker-apim/blob/3.2.x/docker-compose/apim-with-analytics/conf/apim-analytics-dashboard/conf/dashboard/deployment.yaml#L25

Comment: hi sir .shen i run wso2 analytics dashboard and I visit my analytics dashboard this error show on analytics dashboard .what is the reason
[2021-11-22 08:28:14,461]  WARN {org.wso2.msf4j.internal.MSF4JHttpConnectorListener} - Error in http connector listener : 'Remote client closed the connection before initiating outbound response'